# ANDROID_HOME not set (VSTS agent running as service on OS X)

Tags: android, macos, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines

I have configured the VSTS agent on my MacBook Pro and it works perfectly when I manually run it (using `./run.sh`).

However when I configure the VSTS agent to run as a service (using `./svc.sh install` and `./svc.sh start`) and queue a new build in VSTS I receive an error (on the signing step) "ANDROID_HOME not set".

I have the following configured in my .bash_profile:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

The path is correct and also running `echo $ANDROID_HOME` returns the expected value (in this case `/Users/mvanbeusekom/Library/Android/sdk`).

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your agent folder, there is a file named runsvc.sh. Add your export in there. You'll see a commented-out line prompting you where to put your env setup:

```
# insert anything to setup env when running as a service
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Android/sdk
```

Make sure to restart the service.

The reason `.bash_profile` doesn't work for you is because the service doesn't have access to that when it runs.

I had the same problem and found the solution here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/1726#issuecomment-219725321

For those developing with Xamarin, you'll typically need this instead:

```
# insert anything to setup env when running as a service
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
```

Comment: Great! Glad to help!

Comment: Also, you can directly add this line into your run.sh if you are running it not at a service. I ran into this issue today and no matter what I did it wouldn't pick it up unless I added it there.

Comment: Voted for the last bit. Xamarin user here.