# How do I set an environment variable on a Team Foundation Server private macos agent?

Tags: node.js, bash, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run a build on TFS.  One of the steps is setting an environment variable.  This step, a `Shell Script`, fails on the following script:

```
export NODE_CONFIG_DIR= node_modules/test-automation-common/config
```

with a working directory of `$(build.SourcesDirectory)/specmapper`.

I am part of team that uses a shared private agent on a local Macbook Pro. I'm not sure of the exact OS it is running, but I know it's only a year or two old.

I'm trying to figure out how to set an environment variable on this machine. The machine is setup with a bash environment so the following should work:

- export VARNAME=stringofthingyouwant

Due to a diligence of security, I cannot remote into the machine. I have been assured that export should be setup.

I am trying to run automated tests using Protractor and I need to setup a config directory variable that is not available until after `npm install` has been run, so I cannot use the export section in the 'runsvc.sh' as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890362/android-home-not-set-vsts-agent-running-as-service-on-os-x).

---

**Edit:** I was previously trying to use the command line step on a mac, which was now obviously not going to work.  I mistook command line == terminal.  I now have a `Shell Script` as noted above.

I am trying to run a build on TFS. One of the steps is setting an environment variable. This step (command line) fails with the message:

```
Failed which: Not found export: null
undefined failed with error: Failed which: Not found export: null
```

Comment: Check this case to see whether it helps you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179371/shell-set-environment-variables-for-command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the "Shell++" step available as a build step. I determined that environment variables are cleaned up step-to-step, so instead of setting the variable in one step and running my "ng e2e" with an individual "Node" build step in which the previous environment variable wasn't available, I just put both into the "Shell++" as a script.  Works fine now.

Documentation explicitly stating that environment variables are not saved across steps would have been nice to have.

@Giulio Vian's suggestion would probably work if you needed a variable across the whole job, but it did not work in my situation, as the path was not available until after "npm install" had been run.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `##vso[task.setvariable]value` as explained in [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

From a bash script, it is as simple as

`echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=myShinyNewVariable;]aSplendidValueForMyVar`

Comment: I appreciate the comment.  I ended up solving it by running the export and the process requiring the export in the same shell++ script step.  I came to the solution from puzzling out that Environment variables are not saved step to step.